# Is there a way to add more tick marks to the axes? Octave/MatLab

Tags: histogram, octave, axes

I need to add more tick marks between the numbered values on my graph, but I'm not sure how. [image: histogram]

Cannot seem to find a straight answer online

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add certain colors to bar graphs in order to illustrate frequency of the data point on octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71566674/can-i-add-certain-colors-to-bar-graphs-in-order-to-illustrate-frequency-of-the-d)